# Parsing HTML Fragments

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, web-standards

What's the best way to parse fragments of HTML in C#?

For context, I've inherited an application that uses a great deal of composite controls, which is fine, but a good deal of the controls are rendered using a long sequence of literal controls, which is fairly terrifying. I'm trying to get the application into unit tests, and I want to get these controls under tests that will find out if they're generating well formed HTML, and in a dream solution, validate that HTML.

Comment: If the accepted answer is actually the best answer, I think the question title should be edited to reflect that you are not parsing HTML, but XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML is XHTML compliant, you can use the built in System.Xml namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the  [HTMLAgility](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) pack.  It's very compatible with the .NET XmlDocument class, but it much more forgiving about HTML that's not clean/valid XHTML.

Comment: That library seems a little too good - I'm testing the code, so it's a good thing if tags left open blow the parser up.

Comment: You can make it fix the code and output XHTML -- and then compare the input & output.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an [SGMLReader](http://wiki.developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader) to produce a valid Xml document from HTML and then parse what is required using XPath or to another format using XSLT.  .

Answer (score -1):

You can also look into [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) for HTML parsing/cleanup.  I don't think they have specific .NET libraries, but you might be able to run the binary via command-line, or IKVM the java libraries.